# How to perform regression on data with uncertainty?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, measurement-error, uncertainty

There are many resources for linear and polynomial regression, but I have not seen any material where the data comes with its own uncertainty as it appears in the real world. I have n data points, {X_1, ..,X_n} each with its own uncertainty, let's say, {u_1, ..,u_n}, with n observation {Y_1,...,Y_n}. now I want to find function f such that Y=f(X)? Imagine quadratic or cubic functions.

Comment: A common form of this is known as [Deming regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=deming+regression).  To carry it out,  you need to supply some assumptions about the relative sizes of the $X$ and $Y$ uncertainties.  If the $Y$ values have no uncertainty, then this falls under the rubric of [inverse regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22inverse+regression%22).

Comment: Thanks, @whuber. Just wondering is there any resource on handling uncertainty in NeuralNet?  Additionally, any detailed resource for "inverse regression" is appreciated.